# viewWillAppear is running even if viewDidLoad performs a Segue

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8

I am migrating an app to be compatible with ios8.

why is viewWillAppear block running when viewDidLoad is performing a segue? it was not happening in ios7.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    // crashes here when not currentUser:
    NSLog(@"Logged user: %@ my_api_id=%@", currentUser.username, currentUser[@"api_id"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation makes no guarantees about whether or not `viewWillAppear:` gets called when performing a segue in `viewDidLoad`. This is an internal implementation detail that your code shouldn't rely upon.